# Emulator screens look different

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, android-screen

I made an `AVD` with `API 23` that is `nexus 4` and it looks like this

[image]

Not like this with `Buttons & Manu` in separate panel.

[image]

So, I want to know does `Android Studio` provide emulator screen as the original physical device? And not as the 2nd image above? Or I have some problem with my `emulator`. Why my `emulator` have no additional panel with `buttons`?

Guide me please.

Comment: The regular Nexus 4 Phones also don't have any buttons (except volume and power). Why should they have them in the emulator?

Comment: in some emulators keyboard's button are in separate panel as in the above image for that I asked, I did not use android device I works with emulator till

Comment: Have you checked the Hardware Keyboard checkbox?

Comment: may be but not sure.... I try it.

Comment: yeah! Its already checked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this:

- Open SDK Manager
- Go to tools > Manage AVDs
- Edit your AVD and change the skin to "Skin with dynamic hardware controls"

If not and really headache... go for "Genymotion". Works great, free and every single "physical buttons" works. Here: https://www.genymotion.com/#!/download

It looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you please tell me how much space `Genymotion` require

Comment: means space to install and tell how much ram it uses

Comment: Here is the official documentation: https://www.genymotion.com/#!/developers/user-guide at least 2Gb of RAM to run it and 100mb of space for Genymotion... then you can set the SD card size for the emulation

Answer (score 1):

In the Android Studio toolbar:

AVD Manager -> click the pencil icon across your Nexus 4 AVD -> *Show Advanced Settings* -> Scroll all the way to the bottom and select *Enable keyboard input*.